# Ruby/RVM install problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

In trying to update my openSSL, I have uninstalled rvm.  Now I have reinstalled rvm, when I run `rvm -v` I am up to date with:

```
rvm 1.18.15 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

but when I run `ruby -v` I get the following

```
/Users/marty/.rvm/bin/ruby: line 6: /Users/marty/.rvm/bin/ruby: Argument list too long
/Users/marty/.rvm/bin/ruby: line 6: /Users/marty/.rvm/bin/ruby: Undefined error: 0
```

What am I missing to get ruby installed?

I have run `rvm reinstall 1.9.2 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local`

and got the following:

```
/Users/marty/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p320 has already been removed.
/Users/marty/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320 has already been removed.
The provided compiler '/usr/bin/gcc' is LLVM based, it is not yet fully supported by ruby and gems, please read `rvm requirements`.
```

Comment: how did you uninstall rvm ?

Comment: by running 'rvm pkg remove'

Comment: 'rvm reinstall all --force'

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207480/install-ruby-1-9-3-after-ruby-2-0-0-has-been-installed/15213672#15213672

Answer (score 0):

try this answer Running RVM requirements, Skipping brew update - it's not the same question, but the solution + explanation are the same.